# Next & Previous product

Tags: php, woocommerce, navigation

Dears,
I don't have experience in .php so I am asking for help...
I have woocommerce last version and my site is www.regence.be
In product détails, I want to add a previous/next buttons to navigate easily from one product to the next.
Can someone help me to install that?
Thank you,
Pierre

Comment: Your question could use some improvements to make it easier to understand.  You should probably make a link to the site so people can go and see what it looks like now, or better yet, explain it in your question concisely.  Also, what is it that makes two products be next and previous to each other, and is that relationship always symmetrical?  Is it a single chain through all instances?  And what does the back-end look like?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Asking a clear question will make it easier to help you. Including the work that you've done until now and sharing  the error if there is any is very important. please read this article to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To navigate on product details page, (from one product to another product)
you can simply us this code.

```
<?php next_post_link('%link &raquo;'); ?>
<?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link'); ?>
```

Or for more information you can check inside WooCommerce Plugin

"templates > loop > pagination.php" file

Answer (score 0):

Adds Next & Previous navigation on product details page you can use this code in **function.php** file  -

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'single_product_prev_next' );
function single_product_prev_next() {
    if ( is_singular() ) { ?>
        <nav>
            <span class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php previous_post_link('%link', '<i class="icon-right"></i>', FALSE); ?></span>
            <span class="nav-next alignright"><?php next_post_link('%link', '<i class="icon-left"></i>', FALSE); ?></span>
        </nav>
        <?php
        } 
  }
```